# Using "All" as a choice to get all the records from database in Crystal Report

Tags: mysql, crystal-reports

My requirement is to provide `All` as a parameter in Crystal Report. And when user select `All` all record should get displayed without any filtering.

There are many solution available like:

```
If {parameter} = "All" then True else Table.Column = {parameter}
```

This works fine for a single parameter with `All` as an option.
But in my case I have multiple parameters and for each parameter I want to give `All` as an option and in that case using the above solution doesn't help.
Say for e.g. There are 3 params and I have used above solution with `and` clause. 
While running user select `All` for two params and a value for 3rd param still all the records are displaying no filtering is happening.

Comment: Show an example of your code that doesn't work.

Comment: You want `{?parameter}="All" or {table.column}={?parameter}`

Comment: @CoSpringGuy : Eg: If  {?Sales Channel} = "All" then True else {SFA_Opportunity.Sales Channel} = {?Sales Channel} and
If {?Named Accounts} = "All" then True else {SFA_Opportunity.Named Accounts} = {?Named Accounts} and
If {?Opportunity Type} = "All" then True else  {SFA_Opportunity.Type} = {?Opportunity Type} and

Comment: Does all parameters point to same column or different column

Comment: @Siva: They all point to different column..

Comment: @Ryan: Sorry but didn't get what you are trying to say.

Comment: Thanks everyone for trying helping me out. I find out my way: The above syntax is correct the problem was the parameter order I was passing and Select expert expecting was not matching. Hence I was getting the errors or sometime wrong records. Make sure parameter order is same at both place. It will work like a charm. Thanks